# background position effect not work jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

i am not getting background position effect in slow effect.i tried both 'slow' and  100.

I want animate effect when mouse over on image.

this is jsfiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/sNapz/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sNapz/11

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$('#testdiv').hover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({"backgroundPosition-x": 0,"backgroundPosition-y": 50}, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try: `$(this).stop().animate({"backgroundPosition": +300}, 10000);`

**Edit:**
Change css a bit `background-position: 0px 75px;`

Comment: ya it's working fine but i want two parameter x y position of image to  animate